# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 50, 50, 3) for Tensor 'input/X:0', which has shape '(?, 50, 50, 1)'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, opencv

my model input shape is (50,50,1)
I am getting the frame by:

```
 cv2.VideoCapture(0).read()
```

When I'm using np.reshape() function it does not reshape it the desired shape.

```
sized_frame = (cv2.resize(frame, (50,50)))

cv2.waitKey(0)
img_data = np.array(photo)
data = tf.reshape(img_data, (1,50,50,3))
model_out = model.predict([img_data])[0]
print(model_out)
if np.argmax(model_out) == 1:
    str_label = 'Dog'
else:
    str_label = 'Cat'

return str_label
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 50, 50, 3) for Tensor 'input/X:0', which has shape '(?, 50, 50, 1)'
```

Comment: Looks like model is trained on grayscale images.

Comment: Hi, can you please also provide the definition of the Neural Network. If it is Keras just model_out.summary()

Answer (score 0):

The following code should solve your error

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(photo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_data = np.array(gray)
data = tf.reshape(img_data, (1,50,50,1))
model_out = model.predict(img_data)[0]
```

Under the assumption that you trained on Grayscale images

Comment: Got this error: 'ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 2500 elements to shape [1,50,50,3] (7500 elements) for 'Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [50,50], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1,50,50,3].' @CAFEBABE

Comment: sorry copy paste mistake. fixed it should have been 1 at the end. Please note this is under the assumption that you trained the NN with grayscale images

Comment: Hey, changed it as you said but now getting different error: 'ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 50, 50) for Tensor 'input/X:0', which has shape '(?, 50, 50, 1)'' @CAFEBABE

Comment: @GalNeystadt overlooked the `[ ...]` around img_data. It would be helpful if you would provide a minimal unable example in your question.

Comment: I will provide whatever is needed, can you please explain what do you mean in "minimal unable example"? @CAFEBABE

Comment: @GalNeystadt: sorry autocorrect should have been reproducible Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example